# Compiling multiple source files

Tags: c

I have four files containing C code.

`Headers.h`  - (contain all necessary) headers

`AddStudent.h` - that file include Headers.h also introduce some function delegation

`AddStudent.c` - contains functions described in `AddStudent.h`

`main.c` - contains `main()`

The question is how to compile the code with cc ?

Comment: `cc main.c -o main -I.` BUT function implementations should be left in a C file, so AddStuden.h should actually be AddStudent.cpp since they are implementations of functions from AddStudent.h. In this case, you need to do: `cc main.c AddStudent.c -o main -I.`

Comment: homework should be tagged as homework

Comment: I assume you mean addstudent.c (as well as addstudent.h)

Comment: @user1074077, it wasn't, so I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, your probably just need:

```
cc main.c AddStudent.c
```

The *right* thing to do is make a makefile.  Here's a (probably a bit naive) example:

```
myapp: main.o AddStudent.o
  cc -o myapp main.o AddStudent.o

main.o: main.c AddStudent.h Headers.h
  cc -c -o main.o main.c

AddStudent.o: AddStudent.c AddStudent.h Headers.h
  cc -c -o AddStudent.o AddStudent.c
```

The best place to learn about `make` is the [GNU Make Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/).

Bonus note - if you're starting to learn C, you might want to check out [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/).  It gives *way* better error messages than gcc does, in addition to supporting C99 without special flags and being much faster at compiling.

Comment: Can you recommend me what naming convention to use ?

Comment: I think it's fine now - your original post had a typo that made it look weird.

Comment: It's a little bit scary. Will be pain if I have > 20 .h/.c files.

Comment: @user1074077, makefiles support variables and template rules and so forth.  Check out the manual for plenty of examples.

Comment: Just cc main.c AddStudent.c gives an error but with -std=c99 looks fine

Comment: @user1074077, are you using C99 features?  If you are, of course you will have to pass that flag.

Comment: Didn't now that. Thanks again.